# Converting windows form C# application to n-tiered and n-layered service oriented application

Tags: c#, winforms, linq, visual-studio-2012, linq-to-sql

We are working on developing an existing windows form Human Resources program for a hospital which was written in C# , L2S (DBML) and Sql2005, and the queries are hard coded using LINQ

The current application does not support multi-branching concept and I have no experience about this kind on applications, what I know so far about the infrastructure is:

1. There will be a VPN connection between both hospitals
2. The Human Resources department will service both hospitals, it will be central department
3. Each hospital has its own organization chart

based on the above infrastructure, I would like to know what should I make changes in our application?

I am thinking to use Web Service and Repository pattern, is it recommended in our situation? but I am still not sure what to do and what to use and which technology to use

any idea will be highly appreciated

Comment: What is multi-branching?

Comment: @SergeyBerezovskiy same application will be working in both hospitals, each hospital has its own users to access the HR system and as result, i should know each transaction from which branch it came, hope i explained it well

Comment: Seems like you need to change your database model a little. Users should have some BranchId or the like. And for the love of God please separate your business logic from the UI.

Comment: @SergeyBerezovskiy my english is not good, but it is same like sites or many stores but controlled from one application

Comment: @LouayFadel as HighCore suggested, usually in such cases you will have additional table Hospitals, and each hospital-dependent table will have HospitalId FK

Comment: @SergeyBerezovskiy currently we are dealing with 385 tables, i should add new table let us call it Branches and to add foreign keys to all the tables and to execlude the lookup tables?

Comment: @HighCore the problem this application is 4, at that time, we were like build and try developers, now we know our mistakes and we want to try the best and with minimal cost to put the things on the correct track, but we need advises and links if possible to start

Comment: Based on last comment here is one more suggestion: continue as "build and try" developers, but switch to wpf (for greatest UI ever) and mvvm (for cleanest code ever). Also, you mentioned [branching](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Branching_(revision_control)) and that makes me think you already though about changing *source* (so that each client have different exe-file working with different database), in such case (I have no clue if it's an easier option to organize, than adding `Hospitals` table and `hospital` field to related tables) you could simply make database path/name *adjustable*.

Comment: @Sinatr can you explain more about different exe-file please? how can i manage to generate the payroll for both hospitals from same screen in this case? also the branching is not that one in the link, my english is not well, its kind of same application that will manage different hospital details ( users, employees, payroll, leaves...) in different sites

Comment: @LouayFadel, you can't. You run both software (or same software twice with different settings for database) and then combine their output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Phew...I would go for a "traditional" n-layered and n-tiered application. With a central database where users are "separated" by the specific hospital they are working in or for. Although, maybe super-users can also have a complete overview of data from both hospitals.

Why use a VPN connection these days? Is internet connectivity an option?

A traditional setup could be something like this:

1. Database (SQL Server)
2. Data Access Layer (Entity Framework)
3. Web application (ASP.NET MVC) / Windows Application in WPF (MVVM)

A nice introduction about this kind of setup can be followed [here](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/434282/A-N-Tier-Architecture-Sample-with-ASP-NET-MVC-WCF). This may give you some concrete help and pointing you in the right direction.

An initial database design will look something like this (multi-branching ;) :

**Hospital**

- ID
- Name

**Employee**

- ID
- Name
- HospitalID (FK -> Hospital.ID)

**User**

- ID
- Name
- HospitalID (FK -> Hospital.ID)

**Right**

- ID
- Name

**UserRight**

- UserID (FK -> User.ID)
- RightID (FK -> Right.ID)

The multi-branching part is effectuated by the UserRight table. Here users are given (relational coupling) the right to view specific kind of data (employees, salaries, reviews, etc.). The information (business rules) in the UserRight system are translated into the Business Access Layer and the UI. When a user logs in (authenticates) you can then easily enable / disable certain functionalities based upon his or her rights

It must be said that this is a good opportunity for you, your colleagues and your client to opt for a new modern framework to be used. As you already stated Web services, Repository pattern. Be aware that it may take time to become familiar with new techniques and frameworks.

Do a [Google search](https://www.google.nl/search?q=n-layer%20n-tier%20wpf%20mvvm%20sql%20server&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&gws_rd=cr&ei=s1mqVJDHKIurOuihgcgB#q=n-layer%20n-tier%20sql%20server) and get yourself well-informed. Good luck!